# PHP foreach showing values in only first iteration

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I have a custom post type in wordpress for show listings. I have a custom calendar plugin I put together but am having issues pulling all the values from a post over in my for each loop.

When I start the foreach and print out all values, it shows everything fine the first time around but every iteration after it does not display all of the values (such as content).

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $cal->days_in_month; $i++) {
    echo '<li class="date_top"><span class="day">'.$i.'</span><ol>';
    foreach ($cal->events as $event) {
        if($i == date("j", $event['date_object']) && 
                $cal->month_selected == date("n", $event['date_object'])) {

print_r($event); 

        }
    }

    echo '</ol></li>';
}
```

Here is my function to grab the data from the post.

```
function load_month_events() {
        $query = $this->month_events();
        foreach ($query as $post) {
            $event = array();
            $event['title'] = $post->post_title;
            $event['date'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'start_date', true);
            $event['end_date'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'end_date', true);
            $event['permalink'] = get_permalink($post->ID);
            $event['date_object'] = to_date_object($event['date']);
            $content_post = get_post($post->ID);
            $event['content'] = $content_post->post_content;

            $shows_categories = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'shows_category');
            $showseason_string = "";
            foreach($shows_categories as $category) {
                $showseason_string = $showseason_string . $category->slug . " ";
            }
            $event['showseason'] = $showseason_string;
            $this->events[] = $event; 
        }
        $this->duplicate_multiday();
        usort($this->events, "cmp");
    }
```

And an example of the output (it is calling all 31 days of the month correctly and listing the events that are on that day but it's not pulling in the content and end date. )

```
1
Array ( [title] => A choirs line [date] => 20150101 [end_date] => 20150131 [permalink] => http://localhost:8888/shows/a-choirs-line/ [date_object] => 1420070400 [content] => A Choirs Line Content Goes Here [showseason] => 2014-2015-season )
2
Array ( [title] => A choirs line [permalink] => http://localhost:8888/shows/a-choirs-line/ [showseason] => 2014-2015-season [date] => 20150102 [date_object] => 1420156800 )
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide! I feel like I have ran into this before but I can't remember how I solved it and I am banging my head into a wall at this point.

**edit:** The fix was to add the array fields to the funtion duplicate_multiday

```
function duplicate_multiday() {
        foreach($this->events as $event) {
            if($event['end_date'] && $event['date'] != $event['end_date']) {
                $date1 = new DateTime($event['date']);
            $date2 = new DateTime($event['end_date']);
            $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
            for($x=1; $x <= $interval->days; $x++) {
                $new_event = array();
                $new_event['title'] = $event['title'];
                $new_event['permalink'] = $event['permalink'];
                $new_event['content'] = $event['content'];
                $new_event['end_date'] = $event['end_date'];
                $new_event['showseason'] = $event['showseason'];
                error_log($event['showseason']);
                $new_event['date'] = date_format($date1->add(new DateInterval('P1D')), "Ymd");
                $new_event['date_object'] = to_date_object($new_event['date']);
                $this->events[] = $new_event;
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: according to the code you've provided, the problem does not look like with the code you've provided. However, already this indicates that you've got more of a debugging request here than a concrete programming question. Please reset assured that if you provide an array in foreach, it will be iterated as-is. If you miss data within that array it means that you have either not put it into or or you have removed it later. You need to find out first, that is, first check if you inserted the data (test for it!) and if yes, then you have to find out where you remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You modify the data of `$this->events` in  `self::duplicate_multiday()` in which you duplicate events, but you do not copy some of the information like the "`content`" array field you're missing.

Comment: Brilliant, you were right on the money. Thank you. I love having a second pair of eyes. everything is working correctly. Going to edit my post and show what I did to correct the issue. Thanks again!